# Stochastic Integration with Python (Numerical Methods)

Tags: numerical-methods, stochastic, stochastic-process

I wonder if there are some numerical methods besides methods similar to Monte Carlo simulation to solve the below integral with Python.

\int_a^b f(x_t,t)dx_t
where dx_t=c(x_t,t)dt+d(x_t,t)dw_t where dw_t is the Wiener dynamics.

Thank you :)

P.S.: Is there any existing library?